# Waiting for namespace handlers

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi, camel-cxf

I'm upgrading to Fuse 7.3 and getting new errors in any routes that use CXF.

```
  Blueprint bundle ruleEngineService/5.0.2 is waiting for namespace
  handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint]
```

My blueprint.xml contains the correct schema locations, according to all the documentation.  eg. [link](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-cxf/src/main/docs/cxf-component.adoc)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.2.0"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"

xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
```

I haven't changed much since it was working in Fuse 7.0.0.

Features are installed:

```
  cxf                                      | 3.2.7.fuse-731004-redhat-00003  | x        | Started     | cxf-3.2.7.fuse-731004-redhat-00003            |

  camel-cxf                                | 2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003 | x        | Started     | camel-2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003         |
```

The things that set this blueprint apart from ones that are resolving are:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myEndpoint" ...>
```

and

```
<bean id="myRoute" class="com.application.CxfCamelRoute" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" id="serviceRoutes">
    <routeBuilder ref="myRoute" />
</camelContext>
```

where CxfCamelRoute contains a reference to `cxf://bean:myEndpoint?serviceClass="..."`

Regarding blueprint features:

```
admin@root()> features:list | grep blueprint
kie-aries-blueprint                      | 7.11.0.Final                    |          | Uninstalled | karaf-features-core-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final   | KIE Aries Blueprint
camel-blueprint                          | 2.23.2.fuse-740006              |          | Uninstalled | camel-2.23.2.fuse-740006                      |
camel-blueprint                          | 2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003 | x        | Started     | camel-2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003         |
aries-blueprint-spring                   | 4.3.20.RELEASE_1                |          | Uninstalled | spring-legacy-4.2.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003  |
aries-blueprint                          | 4.2.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003  | x        | Started     | standard-4.2.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003       | Aries Blueprint
```

Could it be a conflict between aries-blueprint and camel-blueprint?

I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Why do you have Fuse 7.4 bundles in your server? Since you are using Red Hat Fuse then use the vendors customer portal to get profession support with your upgrade. They are better at helping than SO

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/help uses stackoverflow.  When I do 'features:addurl mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features' it loads them.  I need kie for my rule engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I seem to have solved it.

I added the repo for KIE (`features:addurl mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features`) before doing anything else.  The order change fixed my issue.  It seems as though KIE 7.11.0.Final adds the following repos:

```
mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/RELEASE/xml/features
mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.2.7.fuse-sb2-740011/xml/features
```

The namehandler issue was presumably from some conflict between the Fuse 7.3 libraries, and the latest camel/cxf RELEASE versions.

To me, this feels like a bug, to have KIE 7.11.0.Final use RELEASE features.  It clearly has bad consequences.  But I don't know another way to make `feature:install kie` accessible to my Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `RELEASE` in maven coordinates. You can end up even with Camel 3, when expecting Camel 2. (Never use `LATEST` either).

If you use Fuse to install KIE features, you should *not* install `mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features`

First you have to install *bridge* features that provide feature dependencies for KIE from Fuse:

```
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add mvn:org.jboss.fuse.features/rhba-features/7.6.0.fuse-760014/xml/features
Adding feature url mvn:org.jboss.fuse.features/rhba-features/7.6.0.fuse-760014/xml/features
```

Then you have ton install Fuse variant of Kie features. Not [this one](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/kie-karaf-features-7.11.0.Final-features.xml), but [this one](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/kie-karaf-features-7.11.0.Final-features-fuse.xml)

The description in `kie-karaf-features-7.11.0.Final-features-fuse.xml` is a bit older than current Fuse, because the feature artifactId has changed:

```
   In order to install the below features into Fuse 7, target runtime needs to provide these features:
    - drools7-dependencies
    - jbpm7-dependencies
    - optaplanner-dependencies
    - kie7-remote-dependencies
    - db-dependencies
    - hibernate-dependencies
    - hibernate-validator-dependencies
   These features are contained in some repository not referenced explicitly with <repository> (loose coupling).
   Fuse 7 specific repository is 'mvn:org.jboss.fuse.features/brms-features/VERSION/xml/features'
```

So here's the command:

```
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features-fuse
Adding feature url mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features-fuse
karaf@root()> feature:list|grep kie
kie                                      │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-core-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │ KIE API
kie-ci                                   │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-core-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │ KIE CI
kie-spring                               │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-core-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │ KIE Spring
kie-aries-blueprint                      │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-core-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │ KIE Aries Blueprint
kie-camel                                │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-core-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │
kie-dmn                                  │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-fuse-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │ Kie DMN
kie-server-client                        │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-fuse-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │ KIE Server Client
servlet-api-kie                          │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-fuse-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │
kie-pmml                                 │ 7.11.0.Final                    │          │ Uninstalled │ karaf-features-fuse-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final             │
kie7-remote-dependencies                 │ 0.0.0                           │          │ Uninstalled │ fuse-features-dependencies-droolsjbpm-7.6.0.fuse-760014 │
```